# Why doesn't maven see a specific version of the dependency?

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency

I have a separate project, which I assemble into a jar file, and connect as an external dependency to my main project.

**External project pom.xml**

```
<groupId>my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>artif-idbla</artifactId>
<version>0.9.2</version>
<name></name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

The command to place the jar file in a local repository.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=my.group -DartifactId=artif-idbla -Dversion=0.9.2 -Durl=file:C:/Development/local-maven-repo -DrepositoryId=local-maven-repo -DupdateReleaseInfo=true -Dfile=C:/path/my.jar
```

Then I connect it to the main project.

**Main project pom.xml**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repo</id>
        <url>file://C:/Development/local-maven-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependency>
        <groupId>my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>artif-idbla</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**It works!**

Next, I make changes to my dependency, and I want to generate a new version of the project.I am changing the version from **0.92 to 0.9.21**

**External project pom.xml**

```
<groupId>my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>artif-idbla</artifactId>
<version>0.9.21</version>
<name></name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

I reassemble the jar file and put it in the local repository.

```
-Dversion=0.9.21
```

**Changing the main project pom.xml.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artif-idbla</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.21</version>
</dependency>
```

And I get an error.

Unresolved dependency: 'my.group:artif-idbla:jar:0.9.21'

This is what the local repository looks like.
[image]

**Here is the structure maven-metadata.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
<groupId>my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>artif-idbla</artifactId>
<versioning>
    <release>0.9.21</release>
    <versions>
       <version>0.9.2</version>
       <version>0.9.21</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20220707041151</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
</metadata>
```

For what reason does Maven not see version 0.9.21 but sees 0.9.2 ?

**UPD 1.**
I use Intellij Idea.

When updating pom.xml the main project, I'm trying to update maven.

If version 0.9.2 is specified, everything works if 0.9.21 is not updated.

[image]

[image]

The only output I see in the console.

```
Unresolved dependency: 'my.group:artif-idbla:jar:0.9.21'
```

Comment: Does maven try to look for this dependency online? Is is trying to download it? See the logs

Comment: @Roman I updated my question, where should I look at the logs in this case?

Comment: @Roman I also indicated how I connect my repository.

Comment: What happens if you build from the command line?

Comment: Why do you have defined `<url>file://C:/Development/local-maven-repo</url>` ? What purpose? First `<version>0.9.2</version>` this is the version you have to use. Also using `mvn install` the project instead of using `deploy-file` does not make sense...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have 2 versions 0.9.2 and 0.9.21 why can I use only the first one? What is the meaning of versions then?

Comment: @khmarbaise I need a separate local maven repository for my jar files.